# How to replace existing subdirectory with squashed subtree *and* update it?

Tags: git, git-subtree

(I have to use subtree rather than submodule because the subrepository is designed so that a folder must be maintained inside it. It's a pain, but there is a subdirectory inside this subrepository whose changes belong to the outermost repository.)

I followed this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/ The only change I made was that I used --squash.

I was successful in deleting everything in the subdirectory (except the one inner folder which belongs to the outer repo) and adding the squashed code from the subtree, replacing the copied code with the subtree, all in a single commit. That worked great.

What does not work is the command to synchronize with updates from the subtree. `git pull -s subtree subrepo-name commit-name --squash` deletes everything from both repos and replaces it with content I don't recognize, maybe from another branch.

It's a bit confusing using `read-tree` and `pull -s subtree` rather than `subtree pull`. It seems all this is incompatible with `subtree`. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

(The subtree repo is https://github.com/spark/firmware.)